# Model Selection and inference for mixture of logisitc regressions (or GLM) with heterogenous covariates by component

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references, model-selection, finite-mixture-model

I am facing a problem which should be quite common IMO but for which I don't find relevant contribution. So the situation is this. Let's say that a binary response $Y$ is generated by a mixture of $K$ logistic regressions (but it could be any GLM) each component is determined by a set of different covariates (some of which are shared between components but others are unique to components), so that each component of the mixture have a heterogeneous set of covariates. I haven't found any literature on the inference or model selection for the treatment of this.

Is there any reference article on that topic or any strategy to tackle this particular problem ?

The main problem that I anticipate is that covariates that are jointly not observed for a component generate a set of perfectly correlated missing data which is never ok when estimating coefficients for a regression while off course their true value should in fact be set to 0 for the relevant components. Nevertheless while inferring process and/or the identification of the model I can't see how to tackle this ex ante.